# How to get path to active SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, path

How do you get ask PowerShell for the following path:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER
```

If I open PowerShell and execute the following command:

```
Set-Location SQLSERVER:\SQL
```

PowerShell will change my location to SQLServer. I want the physical path to that SQLServer

I want to script the SQL server management studio's db restore command.

[image]

The above is SQL code is auto-generated from SQL server Management Restore db dialog:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate of the [question you asked 30 minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55269137/powershell-how-to-get-path-to-active-sql-server), just a little further down the path. Update your existing question to show your attempt.

Comment: I had to delete that one. It went in the wrong direction. I'll now have to wait two days to post a bounty so this will once again get attention.

Comment: apologies for the confusion @Larnu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all stored in the registry for the directory paths, and you can retrieve it with `Get-ItemPropertyValue`. First you have to find the instance name that is running on your server.

```
$InstanceName=Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL' -Name 'MSSQLServer'
```

Once you have that you can get the rest easily enough from the Setup key for that instance:

```
$BackupDir     = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\$InstanceName\MSSQLServer" -Name 'BackupDirectory'
$RootDataDir   = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\$InstanceName\Setup" -Name 'SQLDataRoot'
$MasterDataDir = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\$InstanceName\MSSQLServer\Parameters" -Name 'SQLArg0' | ForEach-Object {$_.Substring(2)}
$MasterLogsDir = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\$InstanceName\MSSQLServer\Parameters" -Name 'SQLArg2' | ForEach-Object {$_.Substring(2)}
```

The last two values have some extra characters before the path so I trimmed those, you may want to double check that yours are correct once you get the values. If you want other paths just poke around the MSSQLServer and Setup keys in the registry to find what you're looking for.